# How to hide or move to the bottom or collapse by default headers in default plugin "HTTP Client" in PhpStorm/JetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, httpclient

This is how it looks by default: JSON body has the collapse ability while headers do not.

I have checked the plugin's docs but don't see any acceptable solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not look like it's possible right now.

Here is the ticket that asks for the ability to collapse response headers:
[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239338/Allow-folding-HTTP-response-headers-in-HTTP-client-output) -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.